# $\lambda^2$ is the eigenvalue of the matrix $M^2$ , then the eigenvalue of $M$ is either $\lambda$ or $−\lambda$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $\lambda^2$ is the eigenvalue of the matrix $M^2$  then the eigenvalue of $M$ is either $\lambda$ or $−\lambda$.
Hint: $a^2-b^2 = (a − b)(a + b)$

Can someone give me more hints how solve this task because that hint dont give me anything

Comment: The hint is suggesting you look at $M^2-\lambda^2 I = (M-\lambda I)(M+\lambda I)$. The left side is given to be singular, so the right side must also be singular.

Comment: @Ian could u tell me what i have to do with this now? Because algebra is my weakness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the hint they gave, $$\begin{align}M^2 \vec v=\lambda^2 \vec v\\&\implies (M^2-\lambda^2I)\vec v=\vec 0\\&\implies \det(M^2-\lambda^2 I)=0\\&\implies \det\left((M-\lambda I)(M+\lambda I)\right)=0\\&\implies\det(M-\lambda I)\det(M+\lambda I)=0\\&\implies\text{either/or} \begin{cases}&\det(M-\lambda I)=0\\&\det{(M+\lambda I)=0}\end{cases}\\&\implies ?\end{align}$$

Now we have that either $\det(M-\lambda I)=0$ or $\det(M+\lambda I)=0$. In the first case, this means that $\exists\vec w \text{ such that } M\vec w=\lambda\vec w$, and so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. In the second case, this means that $\exists\vec z \text{ such that } M\vec z=-\lambda\vec z$, and so $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

So we have that one of either $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$  is an eigenvalue of $M$.

Comment: Next step is M = λ either/or M= - λ right?

Comment: @asdfgh No, just because $M$ has an eigenvalue, say $a$, does not mean that $M=aI$.

Comment: @asdfgh No, $\lambda$ is a number not a matrix. What do you know is the case if $det(M-\lambda I)=0$?

Comment: No, $M$ is a matrix, $\lambda$ is a scalar (number), so you can't compare the two like this. Instead, recall that $$M\vec w=\lambda\vec w\iff\det(M-\lambda I)=0$$

Comment: John Doe, unless $\vec w = 0$ ;)

Comment: @Ennar Ah yes, I meant for an eigenvector :)

Comment: @JohnDoe Ok I see that M\vec w=\lambda\vec w\iff\det(M-\lambda I)=0 but what i have to do next?

Comment: @asdfgh edited to answer this.

Comment: \vec w  and \vec z are an eigenvector right?

Comment: @asdfgh Yes, that's correct

Comment: $Mw=\lambda w$ how we know this, that is any fact? where can i find it?

Comment: @asdfgh We know this because we know $\det(M-\lambda I)=0$, which means that there exists a vector $\vec w$ such that $(M-\lambda I)\vec w=\vec 0$, which can be rearranged to give that equation. That is what I was saying in one of my previous comments - [linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251958/lambda2-is-the-eigenvalue-of-the-matrix-m2-then-the-eigenvalue-of-m-i/2251971?noredirect=1#comment4631575_2251971)

Answer (score 1):

When is a number $\alpha$ an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$? Precisely when $A-\lambda I$ is *not invertible* (or is *singular*, depending on terminology).

Suppose that neither $\lambda$ nor $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $M$; then $M-\lambda I$ and $M+\lambda I$ are invertible (or non singular). What can you say about $(M-\lambda I)(M+\lambda I)$?